# Couch DB installed from source binary 1.5.1 doesn't stop from /etc/init.d/couch stop call

Tags: couchdb

Couch DB installed from source binary 1.5.1 doesn't stop from `/etc/init.d/couch stop` call.

The instructions to install couch db are taken from the following link

```
http://asaf.github.io/blog/2013/07/08/installing-couch-db-on-amazon-ami/
```

The couch db doesn't stop with the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the Respawn timeout value which is 5 secs by default.
The work around is to comment out the `COUCHDB_RESPAWN_TIMEOUT=5` from the file

```
/usr/local/etc/default/couchdb
```

after this kill any instances of the couchdb by doing

```
ps -ef | grep couchdb
```

Then do regular start of couch db using sudo `/etc/init.d/couchdb start` and stop using `sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb stop` this time couchdb should start and stop as expected.

Make a note this is for version 1.5.1 downloaded from the couchdb official site and if the instructions in the page `http://asaf.github.io/blog/2013/07/08/installing-couch-db-on-amazon-ami/` are followed for installation.